# Cannot access 'actionCreator' before initialization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Worked with react class-based component with redux before, thought of trying it with a functional component with a similar redux folder structure. But when I import an action creator, say, 'increment' into a component to use it with useDispatch().dispatch() it's showing the 'increment' is not initialized.

**actions/index.js**

```js
export const increment = () => {
    return {
        type: 'increment',
    };
};

export const decrement = () => {
    return {
        type: 'decrement',
    };
};
```

**Counter.jsx**

```
import classes from './Counter.module.css';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { increment, decrement } from '../redux/actions';
const Counter = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const toggleCounterHandler = () => {};
    const counter = useSelector((state) => state.counter.counter);
    console.log(increment);
    const increment = () => {
        dispatch();
    };
    const decrement = () => {
        dispatch();
    };
    return (
        <main className={classes.counter}>
            <h1>Redux Counter</h1>
            <div className={classes.value}>{counter}</div>
            <div>
                <button onClick={increment}>Increment</button>
                <button onClick={decrement}>Decrement</button>
            </div>
            <button onClick={toggleCounterHandler}>Toggle Counter</button>
        </main>
    );
};

export default Counter;
```

During console logging the increment function I get:

> ReferenceError: Cannot access 'increment' before initialization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to dispatch the action

It could look like this, for example:

```
import classes from './Counter.module.css';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { increment, decrement } from '../redux/actions';
const Counter = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const toggleCounterHandler = () => {};
    const counter = useSelector((state) => state.counter.counter);
    const handleIncrement = () => dispatch(increment);
    const handleDecrement = () => dispatch(decrement);

    return (
        <main className={classes.counter}>
            <h1>Redux Counter</h1>
            <div className={classes.value}>{counter}</div>
            <div>
                <button onClick={handleIncrement}>Increment</button>
                <button onClick={handleDecrement}>Decrement</button>
            </div>
            <button onClick={toggleCounterHandler}>Toggle Counter</button>
        </main>
    );
};

export default Counter;
```

Ultimately, the crux of your problem is that you had defined `increment` twice, but you weren't dispatching the action, either.

Comment: Thanks, that's some silly mistake I did, and also we need to run the increment function inside of dispatch, like `dispatch(increment())`